# register_theme_directory() sees custom themes directory, but blank frontend

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have a local WordPress install running, and have included `register_theme_directory('/Users/andyw/Desktop/CMS Repos/WP Theme/wp-content/themes');` in my wp-config.php file.

My WordPress install is at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ig-theme`.

When I go to Appearance > Themes I see the theme in the custom directory, and I can activate it. I can view all its files in Appearance > Editor as well.

My problem is, when I go to the frontend after activating the theme in the custom themes directory there is nothing but a blank white screen. There's no source either when I "view source". I've turned on debugging, and there are no errors or warnings being presented.

**Edit:** Just wanted to add that if I upload the theme to a live web server or even just put it in the actual wp-content/themes directory it works just fine. So this appears to be something aside from the theme itself.

I'm at somewhat of a loss with this. If WordPress can see the theme in the custom directory, and I can activate it or edit its files, why is it not working on the frontend?

Comment: Check error logs. It could be throwing some sort of PHP error that prevents output to the browser.

Comment: There is `[Thu May 04 11:16:37 2017] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Users, referer: http://localhost:8888/ig-theme/wp-admin/themes.php` in my apache logs, but I'm not sure what that means or if it has anything to do with it. Thoughts?

Comment: I'd simplify by putting the theme directory inside your install. So if /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ig-theme is your WP home, put the theme in a subfolder of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ig-theme/wp-content/themes/ as WP expects.